# How to fix "Couldn't match expected type" error in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am a newbie in Haskell and study type classes now. I created a simple type class but unfortunately I am not able to fix

> Couldn't match expected type

```
-- So a can be Int, Float etc
data MyShape a = Circle a -- etc like | Rectangle a a 
  deriving(Show)

class Geo a where
  inflate :: Num b => a -> b -> a
  area :: Num b => a -> b

instance Num a => Geo (MyShape a) where
  inflate (Circle r) x = Circle (r * x)
  area (Circle r) = 3 * r * r
```

It does not like both inflate and area functions.

Error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘b’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          inflate :: forall b. Num b => MyShape a -> b -> MyShape a
        at test2.hs:122:3-9
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration
        at test2.hs:121:10-33
    • In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘x’
      In the first argument of ‘Circle’, namely ‘(r * x)’
      In the expression: Circle (r * x)
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: b (bound at test2.hs:122:22)
        r :: a (bound at test2.hs:122:19)
        inflate :: MyShape a -> b -> MyShape a (bound at test2.hs:122:3)
    |
122 |   inflate (Circle r) x = Circle (r * x)
    |                                      ^
```

Comment: Can you show the *full* error?

Comment: Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘b’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          inflate :: forall b. Num b => MyShape a -> b -> MyShape a
        at test2.hs:122:3-9
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the instance declaration
        at test2.hs:121:10-33
    • In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘x’
      In the first argument of ‘Circle’, namely ‘(r * x)’
      In the expression: Circle (r * x)

Comment: Please put the error in your post above. As you can see, the unformatted version is difficult to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that operations like **`(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`**, and **`(*) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`** require that the *operands* have the *same* type. You can not add an `Int` and an `Integer` together, nor can you multiple a `Float` with a `Double`. There exist some conversions like [**`fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral), but these, to the best of my knowledge, can not convert an arbitrary `Num` type to an arbitrary `Num` type, and furthermore it can result in imprecisions. For example, by converting an `Integer` to a `Float`, you could "lose data".

Your `inflate :: (Geo a, Num b) => a -> b -> a` function, for example, thus results in two different types, the type of the inflate constant `x`, and the type of the values in the circle. Both are `Num` types, but not *per se* the same type.

We can for example make `MyShape` an instance of a class `Geo` like:

```
class Geo a where
  inflate :: Num b => a b -> b -> a b
  area :: Num b => a b -> b
```

and then define an instance like:

```
instance Geo MyShape where
  inflate (Circle r) x = Circle (r * x)
  area (Circle r) = 3 * r * r
```

So here we specified that for a `MyShape b` with `Num b`, that there is an `inflate :: Num b => MyShape b -> b -> MyShape b`, the same for `area :: Num b => MyShap b -> b`.